# How to conditionally import components in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently I'm importing all my components into my App.js file and then using react router to make something that looks like this...

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <Router>
                <Banner />
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    <UnPrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <UnPrivateRoute path="/signup" exact component={Signup} />
                    <UnPrivateRoute path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/contact-us" exact component={Contact} />
                    <Route path="/refund-policy" exact component={RefundPolicy} />
                    <Route path="/privacy-policy" exact component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                    <Route path="/terms-of-use" exact component={TermsOfUse} />
                    <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard' exact roles={['pro']} component={Dashboard} />
  
                    {/* ANOTHER 30 ROUTES */}...

                    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch><Footer />
            </Router>
        </Elements>
    )
}
```

I've now deployed my app and the load times are terrible, my bundle size is around 9MB and I'm looking to try and solve the load times, as they're causing "This website can't be reached" errors for my users sometimes.

From what I've read, is there a way to conditionally import these components so they only load when the user visits the relevant page? Would this significantly increase the initial loading time for my website?
These are the methods I've seen implemented online, but I'm not sure if either are what I need?

```
import("./math").then(math => {
  console.log(math.add(16, 26));
})

and 

<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  component={
    loading
    ? () => <div></div>
    : () => Home
  }
/>

and

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./routes/About'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Are either of these what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading !! You can lazy load your components.

Here is the documentation for the same.

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

However, your 9MB production build is suspicious. Make sure you are building for Production environment and not development. If your project is built with Create React App `npm run build` will create a production build of your app in the build/ folder of your project. Also make sure your images and other media files are not adding up for this. Sometimes we use images as get but we need to adjust them for the web to reduce the render times and bundle size.

**Update:**

Updating my answer so it may be useful to more people. Open your site in `chrome` and in the `developer tool` open `Lighthouse`. Select performance there and generate a report. You can see all the suggestions and what can be improved. In your case there's a lot.

[image]

**Update2**

Since you have a lot of images, lazy loading images is a great idea. You can't lazy load your images as you lazy load your components. You may create a separate reusable component that does the lazy loading of the images. This link can help you going in that direction.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/lazy-loading-images-in-react-for-better-performance-5df73654ea05

However, if you have seen the screenshot on the last update, you still need to reduce the size of your images and gifs.

Comment: I've checked my website using react developer tools and it says it's in production mode. My site is https://theprofitladder.co.uk in case you want to see if you can find any issues on there. I will set up lazy loading, is lazy loading the React.lazy function?

Comment: I also checked and I got my build folder down to 7.8MB, by reducing the image file sizes using a tool on google, but that's still really big. 4.16MB of the build folder is images though because I have around 200 images stored locally, should I store these in an s3 bucket instead?

Comment: All images are not loaded at same time, right?

Comment: One of your images is 4.6 MB. That's the biggest contributor. You should get it under 100Kbs. Your main js bundle is 1.7 MB which is reasonable.

Comment: Yes all the images are loaded at the same time, I have 4 image files for the main groups of images and each one imports about 50 images each and then I import them from there into the components I need them in. So you're saying I should still host them locally, but use React.lazy(() => import('./image1')) to import every image? or is there a better way?

Comment: I've downsized all of the images and the gif, but I just haven't updated my website for a week or so now, hence why they haven't changed on there. Currently my build folder is 6.26MB and the media (images) folder within the build folder is 2.27MB, although the gif file which is only used on the home page is 0.9MB of that, so might take that out if I it's still a problem after I've made all the changes to how I load the sites code. In response to the lazy loading images point you may, do you know how this differs to using the loading='lazy' prop on a standard img tag?

Comment: Thats not how raect lazy loading works. We can lazy load a component so you have an option of wrapping your individual images in separate components and lazy load them whereever you need. But it is wasteful. A lot code duplication. Instead create a reusable component which takes an image and makes it lazy loading in the example link I have shared. That will save a lot of code for you.

Comment: Ok, I see, I'll do that.

Comment: Final thing, would lazy loading the 4 image files not have the same effect?

Comment: Lazy load delays the loading so the first launch will be faster.